Flask app: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getconn' when using connection pool with psycopg2
I am new to Flask development, and I have spent many hours developing my app, but I'm not able to link my database to the app.
I keep getting this error:
AttributeError
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getconn'
I have initialized a pool of connections, which is created successfully, but when I try to query the database, I receive this error. I tested querying my database from the command prompt with no issues, and I checked my RDS instance status, which was "available".
This is my login route:
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        authenticated, user_to_login = authenticate_user(username, password)

        if authenticated:
            login_user(user_to_login)

            # Redirect based on role
            if user_to_login.role == 'admin':
                return redirect(url_for('adminPage'))
            elif user_to_login.role == 'client':
                return redirect(url_for('Clientpage'))
            elif user_to_login.role == 'manager':
                return redirect(url_for('managerPage'))
            else:
                return render_template('login.html')

        else:
            return render_template('login.html', error='Invalid username or password')

    return render_template('login.html')

This is how I initialize the connection pool:
def init_db(targetDbName):
    global connection_pool
    db_credentials = get_secret() #tested function, which retireves correct values

    USERNAME = db_credentials['username']
    PASSWORD = db_credentials['password']
    HOST = 'localhost' #since I am in dev 
    PORT = db_credentials['port']

    connection_pool = psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool(
        minconn=1,
        maxconn=10,
        user=USERNAME,
        password=PASSWORD,
        host=HOST,
        port=PORT,
        database=targetDbName #the name is correct
    )

And finally the authentication function used in the login logic:
def authenticate_user(username, password):
    
    try:

        conn = connection_pool.getconn()
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        select_query = """
            SELECT id, password, role FROM users WHERE username = %s
        """
        cursor.execute(select_query, (username,))
        user = cursor.fetchone()

        if user:
            id, db_password_hash, db_role = user
           
            if check_password_hash(db_password_hash, password):
                print("Success.")
                print(id)
                print(db_role)

                user_to_login = User(id, username, db_role)
                return True, user_to_login
            else:
                print("Wrong password.")
                return False, None
        else:
            print("User not found.")
            return False, None

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return False, None

    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()`

NOTE: I also tried to initialize conn and cursor to None but in that case I obtain a error as they are None.
Thank you in advance for your help!

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getconn' indicates connection_pool in conn = connection_pool is set to None. To question text add  answers to: 1)  Where is init_db() relative to the rest of the code? 1) Why are you using global? You should also read this part of the tutorial Database.



'''init_db()''' is called in the app.py file:
'''if name == 'main':
init_db(DB_NAME)  # Inizializza il database
app.run(debug=True)'''


global as I need to access it across the code, basically from everywhere



What you need to do is read the Tutorial in particular Application setup. Though I would highly suggest reading all the sections of the Tutoriall.

Do you mean that I have a issue in my configuration?

Yes. Read the links I posted, they show how to setup a Flask app.

The code seems to be right. Could it be possible that you are calling to the function authenticate_user before initializing the DB?
Also I would add a try-except when creating the connection to th DB
try:
    connection_pool = psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool(
        minconn=1,
        maxconn=10,
        user=USERNAME,
        password=PASSWORD,
        host=HOST,
        port=PORT,
        database=targetDbName
    )
    #The conn will be successfully created.
    #if not, will jump to the error (and it will tell you what is failing).
except psycopg2.Error as e:
    print(f"Error creating connection pool: {e}")

